# Entity framework conditional entity relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship

**UPDATED**

I have a Notification table as

```
public class Notification
{
   public int SourceType { get; set; }
   public int SourceID { get; set; }
   ....
   // Relations
   public virtual SourceA A { get; set; }
   public virtual SourceB B { get; set; }
}
```

and there are two source tables

```
public class SourceA
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...
   public virtual Notification {get; set;}
}
public class SourceB
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...
   public virtual Notification {get; set;}
}
```

In modelbuilder

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<SourceA>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Notification)
            .WithRequired(x => x.A);

       modelBuilder.Entity<SourceB>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Notification)
            .WithRequired(x => x.B);
```

This is my new query

```
var myNotification = db.Notifications.Select(x => new Notification()
            {
                A= x.A,
                B= x.B,
                SourceID = x.SourceID,    
            }).ToList(); //error
```

I am getting this error `The entity or complex type 'Notification' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query`

The `SourceTypes` are `A` and `B`. how do i make entity relation in `Notification` according to the type of Source?

I used linq `join` on every query to join the related entites according to sourcetypes for now.

I am doing **database first model**.

Comment: An object can have the two relations or are exclusive? Only can have one of them?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it creating a relation 0..1 to many
In SourceA and SourceB you have to add a property to reference to Notification Parent

`public virtual Notification { get; set; }`

And then create 0..1 to many Relation in you Entity Framework configuration

`HasOptional(x => x.SourceA)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Notification);`

`HasOptional(x => x.SourceB)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Notification);`

**Query error**

You can't do a Select with a new in a Query that is executed in Database, this only work in memory collections, to have the value of SourceID you can do something like

`public int SourceID { get return SourceA = !null ? SourceA.ID : SourceB.ID; }`

Comment: where is the relation from the SourceType in here?

Comment: @Ruchan SourceType don't have to be persisted in database it can be a calculated property like `public int SourceType { get {  if SourceA == !null) { return X } else if (SourceB != null) { return Y; } }

Comment: SourceA and SourceB have commond fields, Can they be implemented like a hierarchy?

Comment: Use LazyLoading to get the results for SourceA or SourceB.

Comment: SourceA and SourceB are completely different and have no hierarchy. I tried to do lazy loading and got error something like 'could not create model Notification' when selecting Notifications

Comment: Can you post exactly the error? Are virtual the SourceA and SourceB properties?

Comment: Error is `The entity or complex type 'Notification' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query` yes i made them virtual

Comment: Has notification a Default constructor ? Can you post your Linq method? Check this if it helps you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/48332/error-the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a.aspx